# How to create two LinearLayout with equal width programmatically?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-layoutparams

I'm trying to create two `LinearLayout` with equal width programmatically:
[image]

```
mGroupLayout.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
mGroupLayout.setWeightSum(2f);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        0,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
params.weight = 1.0f;


leftLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
leftLayout.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
leftLayout.setLayoutParams(params);


mGroupLayout.addView(
        leftLayout,
        params
        );

rightLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
rightLayout.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
rightLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

mGroupLayout.addView(
        rightLayout,
        params
        );
```

But all my linear layouts isn't visible (they has 0 width).
How i can do that?

Comment: LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT to match parent, change both param to match parent

Answer (score 5):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        0,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1
        );
FirstLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(params );
SecondLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(params );

1 is the Weight of each layout.
```

Comment: I tried to set weight in constructor of `LayoutParams`, and tried with params.weight = 1 it didn't work. So if i use xml layout it work perfect

Answer (score 1):

Try this out,

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            0,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1.0
            );
```

1.0 if your **weightsum** is 2 else 0.5

Comment: If i use `MATCH_PARENT` as width, my left `LinearLayout` fill all space. And right layout is not visible

Comment: it should not happen as you are giving weight